# Intercept/capture incoming traffic to pods/services in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I'm using Openshift and Kubernetes as cloud platform for my application. For test purposes I need to intercept incoming http requests to my pods. Is this possible to do that with Kubernetes client library or maybe it can be configured with yaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is no, you can't.

One of the ways to overcome this is to exec into your container (`kubectl exec -it <pod> bash`), install tcpdump and run something like `tcpdump -i eth0 -n`.

A more reasonable way to have it solved on infra level is to use some tracing tool like Jaeger/Zipkin

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below it will work. First you need create a job.
Let's say with name (tcpdumppod.yaml)

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: tcpdump-capture-job
  namespace: blue
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: "tcpdumpcapture-pod"
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/hostname: "ip-xx-x-x-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.internal"
      tolerations:
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
          effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
      - name: "job-container"
        image: "docker.io/centos/tools"
        command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "--"]
        args: [ "tcpdump -i any -s0 -vv -n dst host 10.233.6.70 and port 7776 || src 10.233.64.23" ]
      restartPolicy: Never 
  backoffLimit: 3
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 460
```

=> kubectl create -f tcpdumppod.yaml
And check the pod logs which is created by the job when the container is running.

Comment: is this a service or pod ip----------------------------->args: [ "tcpdump -i any -s0 -vv -n dst host 10.233.6.70 and port 7776 || src 10.233.64.23" ]

Comment: @nborpe it is the pod ip